# unisharp laravel filemanager Can't upload image, "Please refresh and try again

Tags: laravel-5, file-manager

I am having trouble as I cannot seem to upload images or anything else and keep getting error messages. exif and mbstring.

A search of the internet only seems to say these are necessary. Of course I have checked the file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the middleware VerifyCsrfToken that is the problem.

Change the except to:

```
protected $except = [
      'laravel-filemanager/*'
    ];
```

It works perfectly then. Why it is not in the documentation is beyond me!